# Strange result accessing javascript object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My question is really short, i can't understand the result of this operation. I am calling the Firebase Authentication API which is giving me this object if the authentication failed:

```
  y {
  a:3
  b:null
  c:null
  f:null
  g:true
  h:false
  i:K {code: "auth/wrong-password", message: "The password is invalid or the 
  user does not have a password."}
  }
```

And this if it was successful:

```
y {a: 0, i: undefined, c: y, b: null, f: null, …}
a:2
b:null
c:null
f:null
g:false
h:false
i:{user: Q, credential: null, additionalUserInfo: Gf, operationType: "signIn"}
```

So one thing i supposed was if it gives "g: true" it failed and if it gives "g: false" it was successful but when i access the element g:

```
console.log(result.g)
```

The result it is always false despite what it says in result object.
I never had this problem, if somebody can help i will appreciate it.

Here is my code for more detail:

```
export default class ApiResource {
  signIn(_user, _password) {
    var result = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_user, _password)
    return result
  }
}
...
var result = new ApiResource().signIn(this.username, this.password)
console.log(result)
console.log(result.g)
```

[This is the result in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JQBE.png)

The auth is a firebase object

```
//Firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase';
const app = initializeApp({
// ...Initialize code here
})

export const auth = app.auth()
```

Comment: add your firebase authentication code.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you write "g" is outside y object.

```
  y {
  a:3
  b:null
  c:null
  f:null
  g:true
```

But for successful:

```
y {}..
g: false
```

You can check if "g" is the correct flag for succesful login.

If so you there are two "g" properties in the request. Maybe you are accessing the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolved my problem using the .then() and .catch() methods because the resultant object was a javascript promise, but i still doesn't understand why the result was false when the object said it was true.
Maybe when i accessed result.g it was not defined yet or something.
Well if someone has the answer to this behavior just let me now.

Comment: It looks like you're reaching into "private" properties and trying to assign them meaning other than what they actually have.  If an API says you're getting a promise, then all you can expect is that it has then() and catch() methods.  After that, you reach into the result object as documented by the API.